# Bootstrap grid and row alignment issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, alignment

I am trying to achieve the following layout as shown on the picture:[image]

I would like both col-xs-8 and col-xs-4 to start at the very same height, so I have put them in one row, and the lower col-xs-8 to an other one. What I get is the following:
[image]

Is there any way to get around this problem and display both columns properly? I would also like both columns to be exactly the same height. The lower col-xs-8, has a fixed height. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `pull-right` class to the second element. This class adds `float:right;` property to the element.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4 bg-warning">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text.</div>
  <div class="col-xs-8 bg-primary pull-right">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 bg-success">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class ='row'>
  <div class='col-md-8'>
    <div style='background:green' class='col-md-12'>a</div>
    <div style='background:yellow' class='col-md-12'>b</div>
  </div>
  <div class='col-md-4'>
    <div style='background:red' class='col-md-12'>c</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

example https://jsfiddle.net/43tq748r/

Comment: It does not work for me, as I have two rows as in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pcnjw6ud/

Answer (score 1):

Try this code and see bootplay link:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 test">
        col-8
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 test1">
        col-8
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 test2">
        col-4
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */

```
.test {
  background-color: #ff0000;
  border: 1px solid;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.test1 {
  background-color: #000000;
  border: 1px solid;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.test2 {
  background-color: #008000;
  border: 1px solid;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

http://www.bootply.com/nR4VPtCzy6

Answer (score 1):

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class ='row'>
  <div class='col-xs-12'>
   <div class="col-xs-8" style="height:50px;background:red">col-xs-8</div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 pull-right" style="background:green;height:200px">col-xs-4</div>
  <div class="col-xs-8" style="background:yellow;height:150px">col-xs-8</div>
</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code and apply height as per your need to each column.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8" style="background-color:lavender;">
       <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12" style="background-color:lavenderblush;height:50px;">col-xs-8</div>
          <div class="col-xs-12" style="background-color:lavenderblush;height:50px;">col-xs-8</div>
       </div>
    </div>
       
    <div class="col-xs-4" style="background-color:lavenderblush;height:100px;">col-xs-4</div>
  </div>
```